# What's the fastest way to rile up an angry, murderous mob to poison for Mosh Pit?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-revelations

For the achievement Mosh Pit, I have to poison 10 guards at once.  I attempted this last night by breaching the palace walls and having 3 sets of Janissaries attack me at the same time.  Despite flinging Desura bombs as if they were full of candy, I didn't manage to get 10 of the poisoned at once.

One of the other achievements also requires that I have a group of 5 guards injured by caltrops and then scaffold'ed, which seems somewhat similar in that I need a whole mess of guards in a relatively confined space.

What's a good way to get a whole bunch of guards together, and what's the best way to get them all poisoned at once?

Comment: yeah let's rile up some mobs!

Comment: Should I get this game? It looks good.

Comment: @SeanGallagher: Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cherry bombs are used for diversion, and are intended to grab the guards attention. They will follow the sound and gather around the area where one explodes.

I've found the best spot to get 10+ together for Most Pit is in the southwest corner of the map near an arch. By the arch are at least 12 guards. You can sit on top of it, throw a cherry bomb to get their attention, wait for them to gather, and then throw a poison bomb. Video here:

Comment: Also if you can wait long enough to try for the achievement, you can wait til you get to **Cappadocia** where guards are everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to poison all the enemies at once. You only need **10 concurrently poisoned enemies** for the achievement. I went to the south west corner of Istanbul then with the guard patrol and the two guys standing guard made for exactly 10 enemies. I thew a couple of datura bombs (British gunpowder and terra cotta shells) and got most of them. The remaining one or two I used the poison blade on. As soon as they are all dancing mad the achievement will pop.

Answer (score 2):

Throw money to the ground, that gets them all in a pack. Another way is to get them all to run after you, the drop one at your feet and stay in it.

Answer (score 2):

I found it very easy to do on sequence 6, memory 2, "Honor, Lost and Won".

Bring along strong impact poison bombs and strong sulfur bombs. Late in the mission, you'll stand in front of a large Janissary crowd, toss a sulfur bomb and the crowd will gather around the spot, now toss all your poison bombs and that should do the trick. If that didn't work, die and try again.

For reference, this is the part of the mission I'm referring to, obvious spoiler is obvious